# Banner component Click URL - relative link not absolute

Tags: component, module

Is there a way to put a relative link (to site root) in the Click URL of a banner item, rather than a fully qualified link? I have a site in development (which will be pushed up to a live server) and want to use a relative to site root link.

Comment: You can simply use `index.php` as the link which will go to the root

Comment: If I use the URL index.php?option=com_sobipro&pid=58&sid=302:king-s-lodge&Itemid=213 it converts it to http:// index.php?option=com_sobipro&pid=58&sid=302:king-s-lodge&Itemid=213 when I save. (without the space)

Comment: I'm a little confused. So what are you expecting the URL to be?

Comment: http:// www.website.com/index.php?option=com_sobipro....
This seems to have been an issue in J2.5 http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/%3Faction%3DTrackerItemEdit%26tracker_item_id%3D28918_/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=30147&start=150

Comment: Hmm that's odd. in the configuration.php, what value do you have for the `$live_site` variable? And what are your SEO Settings in the Global Configuration?

Comment: SEF and rewriting is off. $Livesite is empty

Comment: Try adding your site domain to the `$live_site` variable. Have you made any changes to the htaccess file by any chance?

Comment: Com Banner component of Joomla does not allow to save the link without "http://". If you do not provide http:// in the field value, Com Banner will automatically add it and then saves the link.

Comment: I was going to say, I've just added the livesite path and it really screwed my paths. Looks like I'll just have to update the URLs when it goes live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually an issue with the final version of Joomla 2.5, and they never fixed it and it is still in Joomla 3.3

Looks like no-one bothered to raise the issue with Joomla 3

Here is the tracker

http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/%3Faction%3DTrackerItemEdit%26tracker_item_id%3D28918_/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=30147&start=150

The way to prevent the http:// being added automatically is to

- Download the file {site root}/administrator/components/mod_banners/models/forms/banner.xml
- Find the line (approx 69)

and remove the filter="url" and replace with ""

This will then allow you to put anything in that box. I found that by adding the full internal link of the site i.e

index.php&option=com_content etc etc it worked fine

However due to embedded banner code I found that SEF names didnt work properly.

This will take some trial an error, but at least you will be able to put whatewver you want in the box. Bear in mind, this is not a supported change, nor is it a full solution, its is a small hack pure and simple. All your existing banners with the http:// already added will still work fine as we are only changing the validation of the form, not the way the form actions the data

REMEMBER, as you cant embed this as a template override, any updates to the joomla core may remove this amendment as banner is a core component